# Мера «дружбы» в соц. группе / связности в графе — как считать?

Tags: статистика, графы, алгоритм, множества, математика

В группе в соц. сети N участников. Есть список их id, и для каждого можно получить список друзей. При этом если изобразить их как точки со связями дружбы, выяснится, что существуют отдельные «острова», где все больше или меньше дружат между собой. Эти острова могут быть вообще отдельно от остальных, или иметь 1-2 «случайные» связи одного из участников с другими островами.

Вопрос не слушавшего курс по графам: **что можно считать мерой сдруженности** всей группы, или отдельного «острова»? Представляю некий коэффициент, имеющий максимум, если все 100% дружат со всеми (каждый с каждым из группы), и минимум, ноль, если никто ни с кем не знаком.

И заодно, какой алгоритм считается практичным/эффективным для оценки сдруженности больших сообществ, по неск. миллионов, например?

И до кучи, как находить явные «острова» - где кол-во связей внутри превышает некий порог по сравнению со связями вовне?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Представляю некий коэффициент, имеющий максимум, если все 100% дружат со всеми (каждый с каждым из группы), и минимум, ноль, если никто ни с кем не знаком.

Количество ребер в полносвязном графе равно (N*(N-1))/2, где N - количество вершин. Полносвязный граф - граф, в котором все вершины попарно соединены. Это и есть необходимый вам максимум.

http://e-maxx.ru/algo/ вот тут есть довольно хороший раздел алгоритмов на графы, может найдете что-то для себя